Did you hurt yourself?

Did you hurt yourself?

Does this sentence mean 'you' intentionally tried to hurt 'yourself' or accidentally hurt 'yourself'? In a word, intentionally or accidentally?

Compare Were you hurt?, which in many contexts is completely interchangeable. The only difference is that Did you hurt yourself? always implies you were the only conscious agent whose (perhaps accidental / unintended) actions might have led to your possible harm, whereas Were you hurt? also works fine if someone else (or just circumstances) might have been the cause.

It could mean either. Usually this sentence is used to ask about unintended self-harm. Like, you slipped with a power tool, you yelp, and a friend asks, "Did you hurt yourself?"

Or you simply fell over.

@KateBunting Sure. Many ways one could accidentally hurt oneself, or lead others to believe you may have hurt yourself.

A person who is worried that someone is engaging in self-harm would probably phrase the question using the progressive:

Are you hurting yourself?

or if using the simple past to refer to a particular suspicious scar or wound that is visible to them:

Did you do that to yourself?

The simple past:

Did you hurt yourself?

is more likely to be asked when some incident has occurred nearby, as when someone has fallen, or bumped into something, or has cut themselves when opening a tin of tuna, or has told the other person about such an incident:

I was on my bicycle at the red-light at the corner of Elm and Main, trying to keep my balance just inching along, waiting for the light to change, and I fell over.
-- Oh. Did you hurt yourself?
Just a bruise on my elbow.


I. "Did you hurt yourself" - appropriate situations to ask?
OP has asked

Does this sentence mean 'you' intentionally tried to hurt 'yourself' or accidentally hurt 'yourself'?
In a word, intentionally or accidentally?

This question doesn't mean that the injured person caused harm intentionally. But normally, it should be asked in these situations:

The  person was alone and had an accident (e.g., tripped, fell, etc.)
The cause of the injury is unclear
The person is at fault (e.g., they were careless or reckless)

II. Appropriate questions for injuries by others:.
In cases where someone is hurt due to another person's actions, you should ask:

"Are you okay?"
"Do you need help?"

III. What is meant by asking this?.
This question could be asked even when it is visible that the person is injured. So this question is not a  "yes or no" question. But it is a way to show concern and offer assistance.

When people intentionally hurt themselves because they are experiencing emotional distress and/or they are a victim of abuse: physical or psychological, the expression "self harm" is used. The meaning of the question is therefore unequivocal:

"Did you self-harm?".

